# str_replace not working for two words in different lines

Tags: php, string, replace

I have this code:

```
<?php
$string = "<br>
<br>
Hello
";
$string = str_replace('<br><br>','text',$string);
echo $string;
?>
```

this is not working..

but this works.

```
<?php
$string = "<br><br>
Hello
";
$string = str_replace('<br><br>','text',$string);
echo $string;
?>
```

this is not my real code but i could replicate my problem with this code.I need a solution which will work even if there is no line break. please help me.

Comment: `str_replace` is working well, the first string is `<br>\n<br>`, so, that differs from `<br><br>`, remove all line breaks before the comparison

Comment: Or use `preg_replace()` instead.

Comment: @Sal00m as i said before i need a solution which will work wheter or not there is a line break

Comment: Yo cannot modify string? then you should use preg_replace as @TiMESPLiNTER said

Comment: @Sal00m Thanks.. that's what i'll do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) and the multi-line operator `m` after your regex pattern.

```
$string = preg_replace('/(<br><br>){,2}/m', 'text', $string);
```

Comment: i think this is the best answer because i need not change the string

Answer (score 1):

In your first code, you two tags `<br>`are separated by an invisible character (`\n`), it's why your regex (generated by `str_replace`) doesn't work

This doesn't work

```
<?php
    $string = "<br>
    <br>
    Hello
    ";
    $string = str_replace('<br><br>','text',$string);
    echo $string;
?>
```

But this code will :

```
<?php
    $string = "<br>".
    "<br>
    Hello
    ";
    $string = str_replace('<br><br>','text',$string);
    echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: thanks..for the answer but i cannot change the string..so i will be using preg_replace instead

Answer (score 0):

It's because of "space" characters, remove them using rtrim :

```
$string = str_replace('<br><br>','text',rtrim($string));
```

Note that it will remove **ALL** the spaces and line breaks, so it will also remove the line break before Hello. See what you need to do from it.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no '
' in the first code. There is 
 
. It will look at exact words to change. It means if you had a blank in your `str_replace('<br><br>'` code, it would work.

```
<?php
$string = "<br>
<br>
Hello
";
$string = str_replace('<br><br>','text',$string);
echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for breaks and check it with string .

```
$breaks = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$newtext = str_replace($breaks, "", $string);`
```